# Issues with HTML5-Reset and cfforms

Tags: html, coldfusion, cfform

I am using HTML5-Reset in my pages in a ColdFusion application. The head tag looks like this:

```
<head id="swipeapp" data-template-set="html5-reset">
```

There is also a `<cfform>` in the page. Browsers ignore `data-template-set` and `id` and print the content on the browser itself. I figured out that this is because of `<cfforms>` and found that adding `<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=utf-8">` solves this problem.

With that change, the page works on Chrome and Firefox, but the html5-reset also gets removed. The alignment and styles go for a toss in IE 7 and 8.

Is there any work around to keep the `html5-reset` and use `cfforms`?

Comment: What part of cfform is causing the issue? You're often better off using jquery to accomplish what cfinput tags do, mainly because of issues like this.

Comment: Just having cfform in the file causes this issue. I see that when i have cfform in the file, there is some jquery includes that happen inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: If you're using any of the cf specific form tags, then why use cfform over form?

Comment: @Busches, a major motivation for using cfform/cfinput is that it allows you to accomplish a lot without doing much work.  You probably already knew that.  I'm curious about "cf specific form tags".  What are those?

Comment: @Busches getting form values in the subsequent pages is far easier if I use cfform.

Comment: I meant "Not" using an cf specific form tags, eg. cfinput, cfgrid, etc. Passing the values to the next page shouldn't matter if it's form or cfform.